# Can I use Mapbox to create a web form that finds parks near a location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, mapbox, network

I have run a network analysis in ArcGIS and have all of the trimmed polygons along roads within a half a mile of a park.  I need to find a way to create a web form that takes in an address and spits out parks within a half mile of the specified location.  Can I do this using Mapbox?

Comment: You could use turf.js. Here is a sample similar to your idea, https://www.mapbox.com/blog/coffee-with-turf/

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox does not have an out-of-the-box solution for this use case but you can use their services and API's to create a web app that takes an address and returns features within a radium of that location. Here is an example that does this as well as a blog post that explains more:

https://github.com/mapbox/analysis-demos

https://www.mapbox.com/blog/properties-philly/